# Exoplayer disabling adaptative behaviour (Dash or HLS)

Tags: android, mpeg-dash, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Hi i'm tryng to perform a playback for an adaptative track (dash or hls) but disabling the capability of change to another resolution, is it possible? I'd like to let a fixed quality, no switching dinamically.

I was tryng with `DefaultTrackSelector` class with `setSelectionOverride` method, but with no effect.

**EDITED**

I am testing with this supposed fixed quality selection but with no success:

```
    FixedTrackSelection.Factory fixedTrackSelect = new FixedTrackSelection.Factory();

    //here i select my desired quality
    fixedTrackSelect.createTrackSelection(trackGroupArray.get(0), 3);

    MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride selectionOverride = new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(fixedTrackSelect, exoPlayerTrackIndex, tracks);

    trackSelector.setSelectionOverride(2, trackGroupArray, selectionOverride);
```

**EDITED 2**

Finally i got a fix doing as it follows:

```
    FixedTrackSelection.Factory fixedTrackSelect;
    fixedTrackSelect = new FixedTrackSelection.Factory();
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(fixedTrackSelect);
    trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector.getParameters()
            .withMaxVideoSize(300, 300) //really draw full available layout
            .withMaxVideoBitrate(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

I need to do the same with Exoplayer 1.x but there is no these objects availables.

Comment: What issue are you seeing - do you mean the playback is not working at all? Can you share output, logical etc?

Comment: @Mick i've just added some working code